# Changing x264 settings on the fly

Tags: video, ffmpeg, x264, libx264

I am curious to know if anyone has experience with modifying x264 settings during encoding (this is for testing live streaming hence I need to be able to modify settings based on cpu and upload characteristics).

I saw an API for encoder_reconfig() in x264.h, curious if folks have used that, and if its accessible from ffmpeg? Is it possible to modify a high-level option like 'preset', or do I need to modify individual options like chroma-me, trellis etc.

Comment: All ffmpeg's option can be found in source code `libavcodec/libx264.c`. Generally every codec source file contains a `static const AVOption options[]`, which including its options, default values, descriptions, etc.

Comment: Thanks halfelf! I started looking through the code, it appears the allowable params from libx264.c (reconfig_encoder) is fewer than what seems to be supported by x264.c (encoder_try_reconfig)… Will try to see what all I can play around with.